# R detect file path automatically

Tags: r

Is there a way to make R detect the path of an input file in R script when running in R studio, automatically?

I have the following code

```
input.data <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/haha/Desktop/haha/input.xlsx", "input", header=F, rowIndex=NULL, startRow=1, endRow=21, colIndex=c(1:2))
```

If i were to share the script containing this code, the user will have to change the directory path for the input file before running the code.

I'd like to figure out a way to do this automatically such that the user is able to run the script without needing to change the directory's path.

Comment: Btw when working with files and folder, always check the path of the file exists ...see `?file.exists`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the directory of the script (`basedir`) automatically in this way and then use the directory to access the input file:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)
basedir <- dirname(sub("--file=", "", args[grep("--file=", args)]))

input.data <- read.xlsx(paste0(basedir, "input.xlsx"), "input", header=F, rowIndex=NULL, startRow=1, endRow=21, colIndex=c(1:2)))
```

Comment: thanks. i tried this code but it gave me an error "Error in loadWorkbook(file) : Cannot find input.xlsx".

Comment: Anyone with some suggestions on this one please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file.choose()` to prompt the user to navigate the file.
It would look like this `input.data <- read.xlsx(file.choose(), "input", header=F, rowIndex=NULL, startRow=1, endRow=21, colIndex=c(1:2))`